# Slow JavaScript at the time of form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have a form and I want the submission button to be disabled when the form is submitted

form:

```
                            <form id="LoginForm" onsubmit='disableBtn()' asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login"  >
                                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input asp-for="Email" id="Email" class="form-control mrg15B" type="email" placeholder="ایمیل">
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>

                                    <input asp-for="Password" id="Password" class="form-control mrg15B" type="password" placeholder="کلـمه عبـور">
                                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>

                                    <div class="form-group form-check">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="RememberMe" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RememberMe)
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" id="LoginBtn" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">ورود</button><br>
                                    <br>
                                </div>
                            </form>
```

javascript code:

```
@section Scripts
{
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        function disableBtn() {
            let userName = document.getElementById('Email').value;
            let password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
            if (userName != '' && password != '') {
                let btn = document.getElementById('LoginBtn');
                btn.disabled = true;
                btn.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
                $('#LoginForm').submit();
            }
        }
    </script>

}
```

And I tested:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#LoginForm').submit(function () {
            let userName = document.getElementById('Email').value;
            let password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
            if (userName != '' && password != '') {
                let btn = document.getElementById('LoginBtn');
                btn.disabled = true;
                btn.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
                $('#LoginForm').submit();
            }
           });
        });
```

But it takes a few seconds to reach the `btn.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';` line
PS: if the user does not fill in the input, the validators will work and will not allow submission, in which case the button should not be deactivated.

Thankyou

Comment: Hi @sina, Do you mean when click the submit button, it will submit the form quickly, so there is no prompt message appears, you want to prevent this behavior and show the prompt message? If that is the case, the issue relates the submit button. in your code, you are using the `type="submit"` button, it has the default submit behavior, after click this type button, it will directly submit the form. To prevent this behavior, you could change the type to `button`, like this `type="button"`, or in its button click event use the `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default submit event.

Comment: No, the problem is that it takes about two seconds to reach the line of the `btn.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';`

Comment: It looks like you have an infinite loop. Your submit handler triggers a submit, which triggers the submit handler with triggers a submit, which... This basically hangs the browser, making everything else very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use button click event to submit the form, code like this (remove the `onsubmit='disableBtn()'` from the form tag):

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $(function(){
        $("#LoginBtn").click(function(){
            event.preventDefault(); //prevent the default submit event.
            let userName = document.getElementById('Email').value;
            let password = document.getElementById('Password').value;
                if (userName != '' && password != '') {
                    let btn = document.getElementById('LoginBtn');
                    btn.disabled = true;
                    btn.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
                    $('#LoginForm').submit();
                }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

The result as below:

[image]